# Big-Oh analysis of the running time?

Tags: big-o

For each of the following program fragments, give a Big-Oh analysis of the running time. I have two problems that I am not 100% sure if there right, can somebody help me

Fragment 1:

```
for( int  i  =  0;  i  <  n;  i++ )
      for(  int  j  =  0;  j  <  n  *  n;  j++ )
            for(  int  k  =  0;  k  <  j;  k++ )
                 sum++;
```

Answer: O(n^5) not really sure n*n??

Fragment 2:

```
for(  int  i  =  1;  i  <=  n;  i++ ) 
        for(  int  j  =  1;  j  <=  i  *  i;  j++ )
                             if (j % i == 0)
                   for(  int k  =  0;  k  <  j;  k++)
                  sum++;
```

Answer:O(n^4)

Comment: For the first one, you loop `(n) * (n * n) * (1 + 2 + ... + n * n) = n^3 * n(n+1)/2 = n^3 * (n^2 + n + 1) / 2 = n^5 + ... => O(n^5)`. What is your question about the second one?

Comment: I just like to know if that is the right answer??

Answer (score 0):

Decompose the problem space per loop.  Start from the outermost loop.  What are the loops really going up to?

For the first problem, we have the following pattern.

- The outer loop will run *n* times.
- The outer inner loop will run *n<sup>2</sup>* times, and is not bound by the current value of the inner loop.
- The innermost loop will run up to *j* times, which causes it to be bound by the current value of the outer inner loop.
- All of your steps are in linear chunks, meaning you will go from 0 to your ending condition in a linear fashion.

Here's what the summation actually looks like.

[image: Linear summation, no skipping or stepping over anything.]

So, what would that translate into?  You have to unroll the sums.  It's not going to be O(n<sup>5</sup>), though.

For the second problem, we have the following pattern.

- The outer loop runs up to and including *n* times.
- The outer inner loop runs up to and including *i<sup>2</sup>* times.
- The innermost loop runs up to *j* times, on the condition that `j % i == 0`.  That means that the innermost loop isn't executed *every* time.

I'll leave this problem for you to solve out.  You do have to take the approach of unrolling the sums and reducing them to their algebraic counterparts.

Answer (score -1):

for Fragment 1:

```
 lets say m = n^2
 Sigma(i=0...n)  m Sigma(j=0.....m) j
 => n * (m(m+1)/2)
 => n ^ 5
```

Answer: O(n^5)

for Fragment 2:

```
last loop runs for i-1 times ...
Sigma(i=0...n)  Sigma(j=0.....i-1) Sigma(k=0.....j) k
approximately its Sigma(i=0...n) i^2 
~=> n^3
```

Answer:O(n^3)

Comment: I'm not convinced that the first loop is n^5, since CAS systems seem to be giving me a different result for plotting the loop.  The second loop I'm not entirely sure is n^4, since the innermost loop doesn't execute every time.

Comment: i made a wrong assumption in the counter lengths, thnx for pointing !
since the second loop is considered for only the ((i^2/i) - 1) times we take summation till i-1